# CWP CentOS 7 hostname ssl not working?

Tags: centos, ssl, apache-2.4, centos7, lets-encrypt

My Site..  https://sajjadhsagor.com works with SSL fine.. but when i visit  https://sajjadhsagor.com:2087 and try to login to admin SSL doesn't work anymore.. error says SSL issued to server1.sajjadhsagor.com which is my hostname server... I am using Let's Encrypt Auto SSL.. What i need to do? Please guide me through...Thanks
Server Info : VPS With LAMP Stack on CentOS 7 Server...

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you are using a self signed certificate for the admin area. You should be able to configure whatever is serving it to use the same certificate as you main site which should then solve the issue.

Comment: How do i configure it? Any Tutorial to follow?

Comment: It really should be a case of editing the relevant vhost config to point the ssl config at the LE certs the same as for your main site.

Comment: Sorry! i am new to this thing... Could you show me any Tutorial or Video so that i can follow? I am not familiar With CWP much...